# USB Devices arn't working while Computer has Secure Boot enabled

Tags: windows-10, usb, secure-boot

I have a problem that seems to stem from activating Secure Boot.

I have several customers with Dell desktops running Windows 10 Enterprise, that require Secure Boot to be enabled.

When they initialize it in BIOs and log in, their USB Devices can be seen in Device Manage as there, but there is no accessing them. This includes software Dongles, Readers, storage devices.

At this time, I'm almost out of ideas. I can think of maybe McAfee DLP Endpoint may be blocking them. I do know currently that turning off Secure Boot enables USB Devices again.

This has happened to only 3 out of 100 computers so far.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is contained on these USB devices?  Are you trying to boot from these devices?  Is McAfee installed on all 100 machines?  Please edit your question to provide this valuable relevant required necessary information.